# libcamera: Preview windows only support YUV420

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, buildroot

I have a USB camera connected to a CM4 and I want to output the video through HDMI.  I'm using a custom kernel from buildroot.

I'd like to use libcamera or something similar to avoid needing a desktop manager.

The current problem that I have is that when I type:

`libcamera-still`

I get

`Preview windows only support YUV420`

I can't find much about how to get around this.  Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  Open to suggestions.